# numpy where RGB channel greater than [0,0,0]

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, rgb, axis

Trying to find colors that are not equal black and I need fastest way to do that. Strangle, the code below works for conditions !=. It doesnt work for > or =. Also I dont want to sum the channel and search for values greater than 0 (thats too slow)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(shape=[2,10,3])
x[0,0]=np.array([0,0,255])
x[0,5]=np.array([255,0,0])
x[0,8]=np.array([255,0,0])
x[0,9]=np.array([255,0,0])
x[1,2]=np.array([0,0,255])
x[1,1]=np.array([255,0,0])
x[1,9]=np.array([255,0,0])
x[1,6]=np.array([255,0,0])

indices=(np.where(np.all(x[0,:]!=[0,0,0],axis=-1),))
print('values',x[i])

>> []
```

Thanks for advice in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this to find where the array has at least one non-zero value:

```
x[np.any(x != 0, axis = 2)]
# Or, using np.where as you were:
# np.where(np.any(x!=0, axis=2))
# (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 6, 9]))
```

Example:

```
>>> x
array([[[  0.,   0., 255.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0., 255.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [255.,   0.,   0.]]])

>>> x[np.any(x != 0, axis = 2)]
array([[  0.,   0., 255.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 255.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Comment: See the commented code, you can use the logic I described with `np.where`: `np.where(np.any(x!=0, axis=2))`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt notice at first.